# Making a player jump using physics in Visual Basic?

Tags: physics, basic

I have been trying for some time to implement jumping into the start of my platformer game, but without success. 
I have managed to implement gravity by continuously trying to move the player downwards, and back up if he falls below the bottom of the screen.

```
            Case GAME_STATUS.VOID
                Keyboard_Controls()
                plyer.movePlayer(0, g)
                If plyer.Bottom > Height Then
                    plyer.playerStanding(True)
                    plyer.movePlayer(0, -g)
                Else
                    plyer.playerStanding(False)
                End If
```

What i am struggling with is implementing a "jump" based on real-life physics.
I am an AS level student studying physics, so i am aware of SUVAT and all the equations, and f=ma, but i cannot get my player to jump when the up key is pressed. Any ideas?

Key Event:

```
                Case Keys.W
            If Me.Controls.Contains(gamePanel) And gamePanel.Controls.Contains(plyer) Then
                u = True
            End If
```

My failed attempts at physics:

```
        If u = True Then
        Dim t, v As Double
        t = Get_Elapsed_Time() / 1000
        v = 0.5 + (g * t)
        plyer.movePlayer(0, v)
        'plyer.movePlayer(0, -(g*3))
        'If plyer.Top > 25 Then
        '    plyer.playerStanding(False)
        '    plyer.movePlayer(0, g)
        'End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally cracked it!

Added xVel, yVel into player class and re-implemeted gravity by adjusting the yVel of the player in a subroutine that is called every gameLoop. By doing this, all i had to do was change the yVel to make the player jump. Code below:

In mainLoop (in replace of my previous gravity code):

```
                plyer.nextStep()
                If plyer.Bottom >= Height Then
                    plyer.playerStanding(True)
                    plyer.Location = New Point(plyer.Location.X, (Height - 10))
                Else
                    plyer.playerStanding(False)
                End If
```

In player class:

```
    Public Sub nextStep()
    If standing = False Then
        yVel += g
    Else
        yVel = 0
    End If
    Top += yVel
End Sub

Sub tryToJump()
    If standing Then
        standing = False
        Dim v, s As Double
        v = 0
        s = 75
        yVel = -(Math.Sqrt((v * v) - (2 * -g * s)))
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, when jump key is pressed, it calls tryToJump(), and jumps if the player is standing!